# Disable past dates in datapicker wpf is this possible

Tags: wpf

I have a datapicker in wpf and I have to disable past dates.
I am using a MVVM pattern.
Is it possible?

How do you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `DisplayDateStart` and `DisplayDateEnd` properties of `DatePicker`.  They are dependencies properties so you can supply them via your `DataContext` using MVVM.  Here's the documentation:

- [DatePicker.DisplayDateStart Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend.aspx)

Comment: As @benPearce mentioned in the other answer, this is not enough. IMO this is a defect of the control itself.

Answer (score 3):

Additional to Rick's answer, the DisplayDateStart and DisplayDateEnd only affect the calendar, it does not stop the user from typeing a valid date outside this range.

To do this you could throw an exception in the setter in the bound property in your ViewModel or if you are using IDataErrorInfo, return a validation error message via this[string columnName]

ExceptionValidationRule:

```
<Binding Path="SelectedDate" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"> 
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
      <ExceptionValidationRule />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
  </Binding>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the [`DisplayDateStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) attribute with Today's date

```
<DatePicker Name="dt_StartDateFrom" DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}">
</DatePicker>
```

Make sure you have set the

> xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

in your `<UserControl>` tag to be able to use the `sys:` parameter

P.S. To Disable future dates, you can use [`DisplayDateEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend.aspx) attribute

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30213551) could be a neater solution if your disabled date ranges involve constants that you want keep in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM we can appy custom attributes to do the validation.

```
public Class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged{

   private DateTime _MyDate;
   [FutureDateValidation(ErrorMessage="My Date should not be greater than current Date")]
   public DateTime Mydate{
       get{return _MyDate;}
       set{
          _Mydate=value;
       }
   }


}
```

The implementation for the FutureDateValidation will be given as follows

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    class FutureDateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString;
            DateTime inputDateTime = (DateTime)value;
            if (inputDateTime != null)
            {
                if (inputDateTime > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }

            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```